# Switching frames in a MC in If Statements with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to switch frames in an if statement, when "picking up" items.

Basically I have 3 maps, and with each map picked up, the frame should advance to the next frame. After I pick up one map it DOES advance to the next frame. The problem is when i go to pick up a second map it DOES NOT advance the frame.

Here is my code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, growVisible);

function growVisible(grow: Event) {
if (map1.hitTestPoint(character.x,character.y, true)) {
    darkness.gotoAndStop(currentFrame + 1);
    map1.visible = false;
}
if (map2.hitTestPoint(character.x, character.y, true)) {
    darkness.gotoAndStop(currentFrame + 1);
    map2.visible = false;
}
if (map3.hitTestPoint(character.x, character.y, true)) {
    darkness.gotoAndStop(currentFrame + 1);
    map3.visible = false;
}
}
```

"darkness" is the item im trying to advance a frame. map1, map2, map3, are the items that im picking up to do so.

Ive also tried the code like this with no luck:

```
function growVisible(grow: Event) {
if (map1.hitTestPoint(character.x,character.y, true)) {
    darkness.gotoAndStop(2);
    map1.visible = false;
    if (darkness.currentFrame == 2) {
        darkness.gotoAndStop(3);
    } else if (darkness.currentFrame == 3) {
        darkness.gotoAndStop(4);
    }
} if (map2.hitTestPoint(character.x, character.y, true)) {
    darkness.gotoAndStop(2);
    map2.visible = false;
    if (darkness.currentFrame == 2) {
        darkness.gotoAndStop(3);
    } else if (darkness.currentFrame == 3) {
        darkness.gotoAndStop(4);
    }
} if (map3.hitTestPoint(character.x, character.y, true)) {
    darkness.gotoAndStop(2);
    map3.visible = false;
    if (darkness.currentFrame == 2) {
        darkness.gotoAndStop(3);
    } else if (darkness.currentFrame == 3) {
        darkness.gotoAndStop(4);
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should always say

```
darkness.gotoAndStop(darkness.currentFrame + 1);
```

You want the `darkness`' timeline to advance, right? Just "`currentFrame`" refers to the *current* MovieClips frame which is always stays at 1 I suppose ?

Comment: Or simply use [`darkness.nextFrame()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#nextFrame()) instead.

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions with still no luck. I appreciate the help so far.

Comment: Does the second map still disappear? If so, check if your darkness really have more frames. Try to put in a trace before map2.visible = false: trace("darkness currentframe: " + darkness.currentFrame + ", totalframes: " + darkness.totalFrames); and see what you get in the console